# Как проложить кабель через тоннель?

Tags: установка

Работаю электриком, очень часто бросаем кабеля, и вот должны бросит кабель через непроходимое место. Подскажите что можно придумать, чтоб кабель зацепить и протащить через тоннель, может палку с крюком?

Comment: [Кабелеукладчик](https://ithappens.me/story/1003) же.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вместо второй "е", нужен "ь" по-хорошему.

Comment: Привяжите таксе за хвост веревку и пустите ее в тоннель. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Здесь не место для таких вопросов, но вот вам совет по вашей задаче: берёте кабель, привязываете его лентой или чем либо к палке, затем вместе с палкой помещаете его в тоннель, затем берёте конец палки и лентой крепите к ней другую палку, опять продвигаете вглубь, и так до тех пор, пока не пройдёте его весь насквозь. После этого с другой стороны тоннеля вытаскиваете ваш кабель, отсоединяете его от палки и заодно вытаскиваете все соединённые палки. Задача решена.